# ascii codes for windows keyboard keys and the codes for function keys(F1 - F12) and other keys like shift,capslock,backspace,ctrl etc

Tags: windows, keyboard, ascii, hex

To write a keyboard related application I wanted the list of the ASCII codes of the keys that I have on my keyboard.

It is a windows keyboard :

[image]

From where can I get the codes ? It will be great if I get the codes in hexadecimal notation.

Comment: Which programing language are you using? These are already defined for languages like c#

Comment: @nunespascal `java + c` / `JNI`. Why did you ask this ?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "ASCII codes"? For example, there's no "ASCII code" for "the F1 key" or "the Windows key".

Comment: @Jon Skeet what are the codes used to represent the function keys then,caps lock,shift,etc ? There will be some standard ?

Comment: @Jon Skeet [I came across this page. What type are the codes corresponding the function keys ?](http://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/source/browse/trunk/src/native/jni/org_jnativehook_keyboard_NativeKeyEvent.h#140)

Answer (score 6):

You can get all the `keyCode` values (even for `Function` keys) by running (injecting) following JavaScript code into your browser's console. Paste the following code and press enter. Then click anywhere in the page to remove the cursor from the console.

Then press any key for which you want a keyCode in Hex

Here is the code :

```
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
      code = (e.keyCode);
      console.log("In decimal "+e.keyCode);
      var hex = code.toString(16);
      console.log("In hex "+hex);
    }, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no ascii code for the Function (F1-F12), Control, Windows or Alt keys.

If what you need is ASCII for the characters that is already defined in most languages.

Have a look at this, it also includes the hexadecimal codes

[ASCII Tables with Hex](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: [I came across this page. What type are the codes corresponding the function keys ?](http://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/source/browse/trunk/src/native/jni/org_jnativehook_keyboard_NativeKeyEvent.h#140)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called  **Scancode**
[here](http://www.quadibloc.com/comp/scan.htm) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode). On linux there's a command `showkey` that can print a SCAN code of they pressed key. On Windows, though, you may need to write a program.