# how to return (F1) from 113 key value ?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, onkeydown

when I press F2 then following code in my form keydown event return 113

```
 MessageBox.Show(e.KeyValue.ToString());//If pressed key is F2 ->113
```

but when I want to get the Char from KeyValue from following code then it return "q"

```
 MessageBox.Show(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(113));//return q
```

how can I reach to F2 from 113 keyvalue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As its a `KeyCode` cast to the [`Keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx) enum?

```
((Keys)e.KeyValue).ToString();
```

Comment: And youll need the key modifiers too. 

 if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.F))

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the letter q when you try and get the char value of 113 is because it maps to the ASCII value of q

[image]

And to answer the rest of your question

[ascii codes for windows keyboard keys and the codes for function keys(F1 - F12) and other keys like shift,capslock,backspace,ctrl etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832522/ascii-codes-for-windows-keyboard-keys-and-the-codes-for-function-keysf1-f12)

I found this article here http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/429451-keycode-keyvalue-keydata

> There are KeyUp, KeyDown and KeyPress event. Only the KeyPress event
>   supplies the character code. I don't say ASCII because this code
>   depends on the current language settings; even one code can be
>   generated as a result of pressing a sequence of keys. Even in the
>   simplest cases with English language settings there is no 1:1 mapping
>   between keys and character codes e.g. key A produces ASCII for 'a' or
>   key A produces ASCII for 'A' if cpaslock is on or shift is pressed or
>   'a' of both capslock is on and shift is pressed, etc. Even more there
>   are keys that don't produce ASCII codes - ctrl, alt, shift, F1, F2.,
>   Fx, windows keys, etc

Comment: let me know why in key down it shows return 113 by pressing F2?

Comment: Im not making it up bro... There is no ascii value for the F keys and when you get the int of a char or try and set a char value it maps to the ASCII chart above

Comment: @AMR: do me a favor and try this at home: `Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", Keys.F1, (Int32)Keys.F1);` (`using System.Windows.Forms`)

Comment: @BradChristie I am not sure what you are trying to illustrate. It is pretty clear that Char maps to ASCII and that not only the ASCII table doesn't contain a def for F keys but also 113 is 'q'

Comment: I'm saying that 113 is q, but you're not comparing apples to apples. the only reason this becomes an issue is when you try to direct cast to a char. However, what the OP's _really_ dealing with are key codes, so bringing up the ASCII table, imho, is moot.

Comment: @BradChristie It's not moot because he is confused why he is getting the letter 'q'. It's because he is trying to cast a non-ascii value to char

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the function keys are not actually characters. Frequently, they are mapped as key combinations, like (0, 113). Why do you want the character code for F2?

Comment: because I store the value in db to let user customise assigned key to each functionality

Comment: In that case, I really like alex K's answer. Use the Keys enum. Don't use a char. a function key is not a char. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18466636/8384