# Is it possible to press F5 key in C?

Tags: c, windows

Is it possible to press <kbd>F5</kbd> key through C program, as we Click on .exe of our program then it refresh the system.

Having same question of <kbd>NUMLOCK</kbd> and <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> also

Comment: `NUMLOCK` and `CAPSLOCK` are modifier keys, and are treaded differently than a key like `F5`.

Comment: i have no idea for all actually, you can say a beginner in C System Programming

Comment: What system are you trying to program on?

Comment: Am using win7 , having Turbo C, actually i want to do it through interrupt

Comment: Yes, it is possible. How you would do so is extremely dependent on the operating system you're targeting, among other things (Linux/Unix would be far different than Windows). You're going to need to [edit] to provide much more information about what you're asking in order to receive an answer.

Comment: Take a look at `SetWindowsHookEx` and low level keyboard events.

Comment: probably this might help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832522/ascii-codes-for-windows-keyboard-keys-and-the-codes-for-function-keysf1-f12

Comment: DOS programs runs on a virtual DOS environment in NTDVM or some other VM such as dosbox, not on windows 7. Keyboard related functions in the 2 OSes are completely different. Also, why do you use an ancient compiler like that?

Comment: Do you want code that tricks the system into thinking a key was pressed ("software that presses a key"), or do you only want software that determines if/when the user pressed a key?

Comment: i want code that call such interrupts

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, there's GetAsyncKeyState API. but nothing portable for standard C or C++.it's all OS specific. So for WIN32_API i have simple progrme you can modify as per your requirement

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <limits.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <windows.h> 

int main ( void )
{
  short esc = 0;

  while ( !esc ) {
    esc = GetAsyncKeyState ( VK_ESCAPE );

    if ( GetAsyncKeyState ( VK_UP ) & SHRT_MAX )
      puts ( "Up arrow is pressed" );
    else if ( GetAsyncKeyState ( VK_DOWN ) & SHRT_MAX )
      puts ( "Down arrow is pressed" );
    else if ( GetAsyncKeyState ( VK_LEFT ) & SHRT_MAX )
      puts ( "Left arrow is pressed" );
    else if ( GetAsyncKeyState ( VK_RIGHT ) & SHRT_MAX )
      puts ( "Right arrow is pressed" );
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Also as alternative you mast receive raw input function to scan key board code and defined your own macros for specific key. So as per raw input you can detect key as per your requirement.

Comment: That's a busy loop. And it detects key presses that are made outside this program. It's really not the way forward.