# Sending F2 key over pyserial write

Tags: python, serial-port

I am trying to use pyserial to write or send F2 keystroke over serial port.

I tried:

```
serial.write(chr(115).encode())
```

as 115 is ASCII code for F2. I got this from javascript `getch` function from one of the answers:
[ascii codes for windows keyboard keys and the codes for function keys(F1 - F12) and other keys like shift,capslock,backspace,ctrl etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832522/ascii-codes-for-windows-keyboard-keys-and-the-codes-for-function-keysf1-f12)

For ESC key, I got it working with `chr(27)`.

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to achieve, since what you're trying to do most likely will not work.

Comment: F2 does not have an ASCII code (or any character code).  115 is the ASCII code for 's'.  I am not sure how that relates to F2 - it is not even the correct keyboard or HID _scancode_ for F2 AFAIK.  ESC is an ASCII code - which is why that works.  Why is this tagged "embedded" is the code is running on Windows?  You need to _detect_ the pressing of F2, then send whatever character code or sequence your embedded system will react accordingly to.

Answer (score 0):

These are special sequences that need to be interpreted by receiver.

This describes some of them, and you can see F2 is `^[OQ` or `^[[12~`. (btw, ASCII 115 that you mention is `s`)

Answer (score 0):

In my system, ^[OQ is up arrow key for some reasons.

I finally found from PUTTY manual that F2 is ESC [12~.

Therefore, it is "\x1B[12"

Pass that string into

`serial.write("\x1B[12")`

and it works.

Hope that it is useful for other people. I am actually trying to reboot into BIOS without physically hitting F2 key.